# Copy Range of Cells, Paste into Word, and Format - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a range of cells from Excel, paste it into Word, and format it, using AutoFit to column. How can I do that? This may be done with ListObject but 
I don't want to format it as table in Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign a  `Range` reference to a `ListObject` object - they're not the same thing!

Make a new sheet, with these values in `$A$1:$C$2`:

```
A    B    C
1    2    3
```

Hit "macro recorder", and select "Format as table" from the Ribbon; stop the macro recorder. This code gets generated:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$C$2"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"
End Sub
```

You need to `Add` a `ListObject` by accessing the sheet's `ListObjects` collection, and specifying your source range.

Comment: But I do not want to format it as a table. I just want to copy the cell range, paste it into Word doc, and format it.

Comment: You want a `ListObject` - that's *precisely* what a "table" is...

Comment: Sorry I do not want to format it as table.

Comment: Wow, well you just chameleon'd your question and made it too broad to be answerable. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

(I would post this as a comment to @mats-mug but I can't yet) As a supplement to the answer by @mats-mug and a general good practice, consider not using `ActiveSheet` in your code.  Declare the sheet as a worksheet object.

```
Dim wbSLA as Workbook
Dim wsDetailSLA as Worksheet
    Set wbSLA = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsDetailSLA = wbSLA.Sheets("SLA Details")

'use @mats-mug code here using the worksheet objects instead of ActiveSheet
```